# Flex Bubble Chart

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a histogram with categories and subcategories on the x-axis and a liniar set of regular values on the y-axis. The tasks I have been given is to convert these columns into circles similar to the bubble chart. What would be the easiest way to do this.

Currently...

```
<mx:ColumnChart id="myChart" dataProvider="{acGraph}" showDataTips="true" width="100%" height="100%" fontSize="16" series="{mySeries}">
  <mx:annotationElements>
    <mx:CartesianDataCanvas id="myCanvas" includeInRanges="true"/>
  </mx:annotationElements>
  <mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:CategoryAxis dataProvider="{acGraph}" categoryField="Impact" title="Impact" displayName="Impact"/>
  </mx:horizontalAxis>
  <mx:verticalAxis>
    <mx:LinearAxis id="laVertical" title="Count" displayName="Count"/>
  </mx:verticalAxis>

  <!-- [Generated Dynamicaly]
    <mx:series>
      <mx:ColumnSeries xField="Impact" yField="KBP1" displayName="1. Key Business Process" labelPosition="inside" labelFunction="toolGraphLabel"/>
    </mx:series>
  -->

</mx:ColumnChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Flare Visualisation.Please check [this](http://flare.prefuse.org/) site.